# Bootstrap images not lining up even though cols add up to 12

Tags: bootstrap-4

My gallery of images will not show as a grid , the images just break to the next line?
there is one larger column and I want the four smaller images to sit parallel to the larger one instead of going onto the next line? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="tz-gallery">

        <div class="row portfolio-images">

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <a class="lightbox" href="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg" alt="Bridge">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a class="lightbox" href="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg" alt="Park">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a class="lightbox" href="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg" alt="Tunnel">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row portfolio-images">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a class="lightbox" href="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg" alt="Park">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a class="lightbox" href="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg" alt="Tunnel">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <a class="lightbox" href="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/shutterstock_424808146 2.jpg" alt="Bridge">
                </a>
            </div>
           
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, try adding [d-flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) on the parent `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here you go...**

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.img {
  width: 95%;
}

.bigger {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.set_height {
  height: 30vw;
}

.row_start {
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
}

.row_end {
  height: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='tz-gallery'>

    <div class='row'>

      <div class='col-6 set_height'>
        <a class='lightbox' href='#'>
          <img class='bigger' src='https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg' alt='Bridge'>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class='col-6 set_height set_width'>
        <div class='row_start d-flex align-items-start'>
          <div class='col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end'>
            <a class='lightbox' href='#'>
              <img class='img' src='https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg' alt='Bridge'>
            </a>
            <a class='lightbox' href='#'>
              <img class='img' src='https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg' alt='Bridge'>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row_end d-flex align-items-end'>
          <div class='col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end'>
            <a class='lightbox' href='#'>
              <img class='img' src='https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg' alt='Bridge'>
            </a>
            <a class='lightbox' href='#'>
              <img class='img' src='https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg' alt='Bridge'>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me R.B. Yes that kind of correct but I want the last two images to fall underneath the two smaller ones. So there will be one large image and four images next to it in two columns if that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you - its looking correct when I run the code snippet but when I paste it into my html document its still not right I've uploaded a photo to show you.

Comment: You want the bigger image to be the same height as two rows?

Comment: Yes that is it exactly!

Comment: do you know how I can do this?

Comment: I spent an hour or so working on it, but I hope I got your desired result. :)

Comment: Please, let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: amazing! this worked perfectly. Thanks so much!!